# Trying to Add two sql statements and getting error with SELECT Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

I am new to SQL Server, having two select statements - and i am trying to Put UNION to combine the two.
But i am getting error message  = **A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations**.

how do i assign  @NEWComments variable ??

```
    DECLARE @NEWComments VARCHAR(max)         
    SELECT @NEWComments

    select cast(Comments1 as varchar(max)),cast( Comments2 as varchar(max)),   
    cast(Comments3 as varchar(max)), 
    from TableComments 
    where CommentsID = 1234
    UNION 

    SELECT TOP 2 @NEWComments = COALESCE(@NEWComments,'') + 
    cast(comments as varchar(max)) + ';'  
    FROM [ChildTableComments]
    where CommentsID = 1234
```

please help!!

I am trying to retrieve records from two tables TableComments and ChildTableComments. 
TableComments will have atmax 1 record but the ChildTableComments will have many records for the same CommentsID.

so i tried to get the Top2 records from ChildTableComments and add them and return 1 single column which can be added with TableComments using UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try with this

```
    DECLARE @NEWComments VARCHAR(max);         

    SELECT TOP 2 @NEWComments = @NEWComments + COALESCE(comments,'')
    FROM [ChildTableComments] where CommentsID = 1234;

    select @NEWComments AS Comments, cast(Comments1 as varchar(max)) AS com1,
    cast( Comments2 as varchar(max)) as com2,
    cast(Comments3 as varchar(max)) as com3
    from TableComments  where CommentsID = 1234
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to merge all child comments into one row, you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @NEWComments VARCHAR(max);         
SET @NEWComments = '';

SELECT TOP 2 @NEWComments = @NEWComments + COALESCE(comments,'')
FROM [ChildTableComments]
where CommentsID = 1234;

select cast(Comments1 as varchar(max)) AS com1,
    cast( Comments2 as varchar(max)) as com2,
    cast(Comments3 as varchar(max)) as com3
from TableComments 
where CommentsID = 1234
UNION

SELECT @NEWComments AS com1,
    null as com2,
    null as com3;
```

Comment: Could you try now? If you still getting the error - in which line?

Comment: SELECT TOP 2 @NEWComments += COALESCE(comments,'') in this line i am getting error

Comment: I've edited my solution, please try again. I'm sitting at SQL2012 so I don't have a way to test it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. But the `UNION` has to have the same number of columns. I am not getting what you are trying to do with the assignment. But here is a suggestion that might work. I am not sure what `Comments2` and `Comments3` should be in `UNION` statement:

```
DECLARE @NEWComments VARCHAR(max)         
SELECT @NEWComments

select 
    cast(Comments1 as varchar(max)) Comments1,
    cast(Comments2 as varchar(max)) Comments2,   
    cast(Comments3 as varchar(max)) Comments3, 
from 
    TableComments 
where 
    CommentsID = 1234
UNION 

SELECT TOP 2 
    COALESCE(@NEWComments,'') + cast(comments as varchar(max)) + ';'  AS Comments1,
    '???' AS Comments2,
    '???' AS Comments3
FROM [ChildTableComments]
where CommentsID = 1234
```

Comment: Please have a look at my comments and advise.